# What is the platform-independent mypy type annotation for asyncio event loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, type-hinting, mypy

I want to write `mypy`-typed code that uses `asyncio` and works on multiple platforms. Specifically, I often have classes and methods that explicitly bind to an event loop. I want to provide a type annotation for the event loop.

When I check the type of the `asyncio` event loop on Linux, I get:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> type(asyncio.get_event_loop())
<class 'asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop'>
```

This type is clearly tied to the Unix/Linux platform.

Now, I can write code that explicitly types the event loop with this type:

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio.unix_events import _UnixSelectorEventLoop  # type: ignore
def func(loop: _UnixSelectorEventLoop) -> None:
    print(loop)
func(asyncio.get_event_loop())
```

But you'll notice that I have to include a `# type: ignore` tag on the the `_UnixSelectorEventLoop` import because `asyncio.unix_events` has no type stubs. I am also hesitant to import a method that is intended to be private, as indicated by the the underscore at the start of the class name.

As an alternative, I can use `AbstractEventLoop` as the type:

```py
import asyncio
def func(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> None:
    print(loop)
func(asyncio.get_event_loop())
```

And this passes a mypy type check successfully. I am hesitant to use `AbstractEventLoop` as my type because it is an abstract type.

Is there an alternative type signature that works across platforms, does not require the use of abstract class definitions, and passes mypy type checking?

Comment: "I am hesitant to use AbstractEventLoop as my type because it is an abstract type." - that shouldn't make you hesitant. Abstract types are a perfectly natural thing to use as an annotation. They're often preferable to concrete types, even.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the CPython source code, `AbstractEventLoop` is actually the correct, OS independent definition of the event loop.

You can find the source code in question [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/14284b0e71c2110f94941b774478fb594d0ef192/Lib/asyncio/events.py#L204).

So I think, you are actually right, and should feel good about this type-hint choice.